# Amazon EC2 instance not able to make HTTP connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon EC2 so please excuse me if I'm asking a stupid question. I created an instance using "Amazon Linux AMI" and installed NodeJS in it.

I added the following IP table entry for forwarding all the request from port 80 to 3000.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

and I created a hello world script to test this installation.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  // Send the HTTP header
  // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
  // Content Type: text/plain
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  // Send the response body as "Hello World"
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Here the issue is when I try to ping to my instance for command line, the request is timing out

```
ping ec2-52-26-59-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

PING ec2-52-26-59-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (52.26.59.26): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check the security group whether the port 3000 open?

Comment: I didn't add any security rules so far should I need to add that? could you please tell me what I need to add there?

Comment: Default security rules heavily restrict open ports. Refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Check the security group attached the the EC instance, port 3000 is not open by default, you might need to open it.

Comment: How can open the 3000 port? what i should add in the security group edit page? can I add Type : Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 3000 and Source : My IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the EC2 instance's security group to allow:

`protocol: TCP, port: 3000, source: My IP`

Or you could change the source to Everywhere if you want to open it up to everyone on the internet.

Comment: it's working fine and I configured cloudfront for HTTPS access. It is showing HTTPS when I access using the cloudfront url randomtext.cloudfront.net but when i try to access using my domain name which i have give in "Alternate Domain Names" it is showing only in HTTP connection. How I can make it HTTPS?

Comment: take a look at this : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html ... I'd recommend you start a new question if you can't find an answer ins this link OR previous StackOverflow questions :)

Comment: I couldn't make it working? i want HTTPS in my domain name what I should do?